# Regular expression for validating input string in R

Tags: regex, r, pcre

I am trying to write a regular expression in R to validate user input and run program accordingly. 
3 types of queries are expected, all are character vectors.

```
query1 = "Oct4[Title/Abstract] AND BCR-ABL1[Title/Abstract] 
         AND stem cells[Title] AND (2000[PDAT] :2015[PDAT])"
query2 <-c("26527521","26711930","26314551")
```

The following code works. But the challenge is restricting special characters in both the cases

```
all(grepl("[A-Za-z]+",query,perl=TRUE)) validates False for query 2
```

or as @sebkopf suggested

```
all(grepl("^[0-9 ,]+$", query)) # evaluates to TRUE only for query 2
```

However, query 1 also takes in year as input, which means it numeric input should be accepted for query 1. To add complexity, `space , . - [] ()` are allowed in query1.  And, the format for query2, Should be ONLY numbers, separated by `, or space`. Anything else should throw an error.
How to incorporate both these conditions as part of R regular expression ? So that, the following `if conditions` are validated accordingly to run respective codes ?

```
 if (grepl("regex for query 1& 2",query,perl=TRUE) == True {
 Run code 1
} else { print ("these characters are not allowed @ ! & % # * ~ `_ = +") }  
 if (grepl("regex for query3",query,perl=TRUE) == True {
 Run code 2
} else { print ("these characters are not allowed @ ! & % # * ~ `_ = + [] () - . ")}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, overseen. Looking for as solution that will allow some special characters and restrict other ?

Comment: Then please remove what is redundant and only keep what is related to the issue. And an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, this is not related to perl, but to PCRE (or TRE, or ICU - R uses different regex engines in different modules)

Comment: Thank you, I removed the perl tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current regexps you are just looking for the occurence of the pattern (`"[A-Za-z]+"`) *anywhere* in  the query. If you want to specifically only allow certain character patterns, you need to make sure it matches across the whole query using `"^...$"`.

With regular expressions there's always multiple ways of doing anything but to provide an example for matching a query without specific special characters (but everything else allowed), you could use the following (here wrapped in `all` to account for your `query3` being a vector):

```
all(grepl("^[^@!&%#*~`_=+]+$", query)) # evaluates to TRUE for your query1, 2 & 3
```

For instead doing the positive match to only catch queries that are numbers plus space and comma:

```
all(grepl("^[0-9 ,]+$", query)) # evaluates to TRUE only for query3
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The second part is great for matching the query3 format. However, I don't want to evaluate true for all the 3 together (your 1st part of code). If you check the `if condition statement` If it is a query3 format, i need to run a different code. So, one regex that evaluate True for only query 1&2 is what required. Thank you

Comment: How about two nested `if` statments? that seems easiest, i.e. `if (all(grepl("^[^@!&%#*~_=+]+$", query))) { if (all(grepl("^[0-9 ,]+$", query))) { print("query3") } else { print("query1 and 2") }  } else { print("not allowed" }`